# Equivalence of the category of covariant functors and the category of contravariant functors

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. Then we have the category $\mathcal{C}^{\vee}$ of contravariant functors from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{Sets}$ which is the category of sets. In the textbook "Sheaves on manifolds" written by Kashiwara-Schapira, the opposite category $(\mathcal{C}^{\vee})^{opp}$ is equivalent to the category of covariant functors from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{Sets}$. It means that there is an equivalence of categories between them.

But I don't know how to define such equivalnce of categories.

Comment: I do not know if I understand your question correctly or not.. Fix a category $\mathcal{C}$... Are you trying to associate **a covariant functor $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \text{Set}$** given **a contravariant functor $G:\mathcal{C}^{op}\rightarrow \text{Set}$** and the other way?

Comment: Are you sure $\mathcal{C}^{\vee}$ denotes contravariant functors? I was able to find another book by Kashiwara-Shapira, Categories and Sheaves, where that is their notation for the opposite of the category of covariant functors.

Comment: I don't think it's quite what you've said here, but it sounds like what Kashiwara and Schapira state may amount to the fact that $\text{Fun}(\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}},\mathcal{D}^{\text{op}})\cong \text{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D})^{\text{op}}$, the proof of which is a good exercise if you've never seen it before. (Start by thinking about why there is a bijection on the objects of these categories.)

Comment: For the record: As currently formulated, the statement attributed to Kashiwara=Schapira in the question is wrong, even when $\mathcal C$ is the 1-object, 1-morphism category. I therefore agree with the other comments that one should look for either a typo in the book or a mis-transcription in the question.